# Dealing with wacky encodings in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have a Python script that pulls in data from many sources (databases, files, etc.). Supposedly, all the strings are unicode, but what I end up getting is any variation on the following theme (as returned by `repr()`):

```
u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'
u'D\xc3\xa9cor'
'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'
'D\xc3\xa9cor'
```

Is there a reliable way to take any four of the above strings and return the proper unicode string?

```
u'D\xe9cor' # --> Décor
```

The only way I can think of right now uses `eval()`, `replace()`, and a deep, burning shame that will never wash away.

Comment: There are no wacky encodings, only wacky programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just [UTF-8 data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Use [`.decode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) to convert it into `unicode`.

```
>>> 'D\xc3\xa9cor'.decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
```

You can perform an additional string-escape decode for the `'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'` case.

```
>>> 'D\xc3\xa9cor'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
>>> 'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
>>> u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
```

To handle the 2nd case as well, you need to detect if the input is `unicode`, and convert it into a `str` first.

```
>>> def conv(s):
...   if isinstance(s, unicode):
...     s = s.encode('iso-8859-1')
...   return s.decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')
... 
>>> map(conv, [u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor', u'D\xc3\xa9cor', 'D\\xc3\\xa9cor', 'D\xc3\xa9cor'])
[u'D\xe9cor', u'D\xe9cor', u'D\xe9cor', u'D\xe9cor']
```

Comment: It works for that particular case. However:

    u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor' --> u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor', 
    u'D\xc3\xa9cor'   --> UnicodeEncodeError, 
    'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'  --> u'D\\xc3\\xa9cor',

Comment: @Tyson: It can't work for all cases. How can you make sure `'D:\\xc3\\xa9\\xc3xa9.png'` is really a UTF-8 encoded string, not a Windows path name?

Comment: I can assume that none of the data I'm receiving are Windows pathnames.

Comment: @Tyson: In the comment you say `UnicodeEncodeError`. Notice that it's **En**code, not **De**code. Out of curiosity: Are you printing it out inside a loop (in a console or window)? It's just a wild guess on a Monday morning...

Comment: For debugging, yeah, I was tossing it out to `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

Write adapters that know which transformations should be applied to their sources.

```
>>> 'D\xc3\xa9cor'.decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
>>> 'D\\xc3\\xa9cor'.decode('string-escape').decode('utf-8')
u'D\xe9cor'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came to before I saw KennyTM's proper, more concise soltion:

```
def ensure_unicode(string):
    try:
        string = string.decode('string-escape').decode('string-escape')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        string = string.encode('raw_unicode_escape')

    return unicode(string, 'utf-8')
```